# How to implement a "Lock"-Layer in exisiting service structure

Tags: java, spring, transactions, service, locking

current situation: I have a service with several typical service methods like create(), remove(), findXy(), .. etc. Now I want to prevent two different service calls at the same time, meaning I want to lock my servicecall, after entering it the first time, so the second client (or same client again) will only enter the method as soon as first client is done.

For locking purposes we normally use ReentrantLocks. They work perfectly fine. But now i am doubting on how to implement these ReentrantLocks, since I dont want to insert them in every single method. Moreover our servicelayers define their Transaction context already on their own, which means, when I would integrate them in the method itself, a transaction is already started before the lock has happen.

```
public class WorkerServiceServerImpl implements WorkerServiceRemote
{
  private static final ReentrantLock workerLock = new ReentrantLock( true );

  @Autowired
  private WorkerDao                 workerDao;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public int createWorker( int projectId ) throws RemoteException
  {
    workerLock.lock();//NO GOOD! Transaction already started!

    try
    {
      workerDao.create( projectId );

      //Do some more stuff...
    }
    finally
    {
      workerLock.unlock();//Unlock, next request can be handled!
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Of course I could create a ServiceLayer above this WorkerServiceImpl class and just forward the calls to the original service, but since I have like 30 services I wonder, if there are any global solutions to solve this issue. Or is it possible to create an own annotation which fires before a transaction is started?

Any ideas are welcome, thanks in advance!
ymene

EDIT: I choose CRUD methods for simplicity. Of course those service calls are far more advanced and can call different CRUD-Methods within one call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points that can be made regarding this design:

- The need to apply locks to service methods looks strange. If you have some problems with concurrent execution of service methods, perhaps it would be better to solve them by proper configuration of transactions when accessing an underlying database.
- `unlock()` must be called inside a `finally` block.
- If your service is singleton, your use of `ReentrantLock` is equivalent to marking your methods `synchronized`.
- You can create an aspect to apply synchronization to your methods. See [7. Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), especially [7.2.4.7 Advice ordering](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering).

Comment: I'm nitpicking, but if the service is not a singleton, then its implementation is not equivalent to marking the methods synchronized, because the lock is static.

Comment: Answering point by point: 1) Sometimes it happens that some service calls are not allowed to happen, before others are done, which is why we want to lock them. 2) Of course in finally block, just left it out for simplycity, will correct it in example. 3) there are other benifits of reentrant lock, for example we can lock more then just a single method within one lock. Probably really no need for static there, since our service is a singleton. 4) I will check this chapter out, thank you!

Comment: @ymene: `synchronized` doesn't lock the single method too - it's equivalent to `syncronized(this) { ... }`, so that all `synchronized` methods of the class are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @axtavt but I dont wonna make all methods mutually exclusive but special ones, which I want to be able to declare on my own. Are there any disadvantages in using a ReentrantLock over synchronized?

Comment: @ymene: No, except for verbosity.

Comment: @axtavt Sorry for bringing this up again, but I am still thinking about your words. You said „If you have some problems with concurrent execution of service methods, perhaps it would be better to solve them by proper configuration..“. 
Indeed that is the problem. Let’s say I have an entity account and several servicemethods who can change its value due to some calculations. Currently each service-method is transactional (required) annotated. Am I not supposed to lock every servicemethod who can change the accounts value as well as soon as servicemethod is called in a multi user environment?

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using Spring, you could define a singleton LockInterceptor, and put it in your interceptor stack before the transaction interceptor. This interceptor would be very simple :

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.*;
public class LockInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public synchronized Object invoke(MethodInvocation mi) throws Throwable {
        return mi.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: this possibility looks quite interesting. I will try to make it work and give response.

Comment: I liked your idea and it worked fine, but ppl thought it would be "too magic", so they prefer an independent service layer. But thanks for your response!